# ReferenceError: $ is not defined (WebdriverIO)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, appium-android, webdriver-io-v4

I'm launching native apps with the help of WebdriverIO and mocha, but unable to communicate with the device, but able to launch the application but not interact with the element.

#### android_app_test.js

```
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
const androidOptions = require('../../../helpers/caps').androidOptions;
const assert = require('chai').assert;

androidOptions.capabilities.appPackage = "com.google.android.calculator"
androidOptions.capabilities.appActivity = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"

describe('Create Chrome web session', function () {
    
    let client;

    before(async function () {
        client = await webdriverio.remote(androidOptions)
    });

    after(async function () {
        await client.deleteSession();
    });

    it('should create and destroy Android browser session', async function () {
        const elem = await $('#digit_2')
        elem.waitForDisplayed(3000);

        await client.touchClick('digit_2');
    });
});
```

#### config.js

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'), fs = require('fs');

var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'mochawesome-screenshots',
    reporterOptions: {
        reportDir: 'customReportDir',
        reportName: 'customReportName',
        reportTitle: 'customReportTitle',
        reportPageTitle: 'customReportPageTitle',
        takePassedScreenshot: true,
        clearOldScreenshots: true,
        shortScrFileNames: true,
        jsonReport: false,
        multiReport: false
    },
    timeout: 600000,
})

var file = ['./test/basic/app/']; //location of the test js

for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    fs.readdirSync(file[i]).forEach(function (filename) {
        mocha.addFile(file[i] + filename);
    });
}

mocha.run(function (failures) {
    process.on('exit', function () {
        process.exit(failures);
    });
});
```

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha config.js"
  },
```

Not sure about that, i think something was wrong in my configuration or else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The `$` global is added through the WebdriverIO test runner](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html). Since you're using wdio through standalone mode, you don't get access to those globals. Try this instead:

```js
const elem = await client.$('#digit_2')
```

Comment: Hey @Kevin  , i had tried but unable to click on that element 

    `const  elem  =  await  client.$('#digit_2')`
    `await  elem.click();`

and found below error

     `invalid selector: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session`

Comment: Ah, that's because CSS selectors don't work inside of mobile apps (which is what's leading to that error). Here are the selector strategies available: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/#selector-strategies

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're using the newest version of Webdriver.io.  Webdriver.io v5 is the latest version that also implements the `$('selector')` shortcut.

If you're using Webdriver.io v4 - you may still need to use `browser.element('selector')` to find your elements.

It appears from the tags in your question, and the code you posted you maybe on version 4.

Answer (score -3):

`$` is usually used as a shorthand to run JQuery functions (such as your `$('#digit_2')`, in the "android_app_test.js" file).

From the [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html)'s doc:

`The $ command is a short way to call the findElement command in order to fetch a single element on the page. It returns an object that with an extended prototype to call action commands without passing in a selector. However if you still pass in a selector it will look for that element first and call the action on that element.`

To fix this you have to install JQuery with this commands:

In a terminal run:

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

then import it at the top of your "android_app_test.js" file like this

`import * as $ from "jquery";`

Comment: WebdriverIO uses $ similar to jQuery, but adding jQuery will in no way help this situation.